# Word for a public place where people frequently come in contact with one another

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

Is there a word for a place where people frequently come in contact with one another? This is like an intersection but in the context of general habitable places. For example,

> [...]as I was running up and down to calm down my stupid dog so that
>   he won't go out and bite people and/or bring bring back a piece of raw
>   flesh and/or throw up a massive vomit somewhere ***_*_**.

Comment: You mean *a place that **people** frequently come in contact with* -- places don't come in contact, people do. :)

Comment: A *busy* place, in common parlance.

Comment: The only place I've ever heard of that comes in contact with people is [Brigadoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigadoon) instead of the other way around, and the frequency is only once per century. Oh, possibly [Laputa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laputa) as well.

Comment: @Robusto: the Symplegades which Jason and the Argonauts just avoided.

Comment: @Robusto We have one of those today, you know.  It’s called [Black Rock City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_Man).  It’s something of a mash-up between Mad Max and Mardi Gras, in a one-week-per-year Brigadoonish kind of fantasy world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The words "busy" or "bustling" fill in the blank in your example sentence, or they could be used in combination with some form of "public place" to fit your need.

> busy (adj.) full of or characterized by activity: a busy life.
>
> bustling (adj.) to abound or teem with something; display an abundance
>   of something; teem (often followed by with  ): The office bustled with
>   people and activity.

Answer (score 6):

... somewhere ***public***.

Or

... somewhere ***heavily trafficked***.

Comment: or *You wanna go where everybody knows your name.*

Answer (score 5):

It's a little bit literary, but *frequented* or *well frequented*.

In less formal language I would say *somewhere where people go*.

Answer (score 2):

In Ancient Greece, it was the **agora**. It is difficult to find a modern english equivalent. A few hundred years ago, it was the public square or the market place. Last century, it might have been called the "High Street". I fear that in 2012 it may "the mall".